# IOS: stop a loop of UIAlert

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uialertview

I have this code:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
      if(buttonIndex == 0)
      {

      }
      else if(buttonIndex == 1)
      {
           UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Danger" 
                                                        message:@"war"
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];

      }
}
```

but but every time i push ok of this UIAlert it return inside this delegate method; how can I solve this thing? Can I use a BOOL for the control?

Comment: You can check the index of the cancel button (instead of hard coding it like you do) with `[alertView cancelButtonIndex]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the delegate of the second `alertView` to nil.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Danger" 
                                                    message:@"war"
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

However, if you wish to add options to the second on in the future, you can set a `tag` value to the `alertView` and check the tags on call of the delegate method. Depending on the `tag` value you would perform a different task.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `tag` property of the altertView to 1 like this

```
alertView.tag = 1;
```

and change your code to:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

      if ([alertView tag] != 1) {
          if(buttonIndex == 0)
          {

          }
          else if(buttonIndex == 1)
          {
               UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Danger" 
                                                        message:@"war"
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
              alertView.tag = 1;
              [alertView show];
              [alertView release];

          }
       }
}
```

You could also change the delegate of the alert view.

Answer (score 0):

you can't stop it **until and unless** you set the `delegate` property `nil` .

Use as below

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
          if(buttonIndex == 0)
          {

          }
          else if(buttonIndex == 1)
          {
               UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Danger" 
                                                        message:@"war"
                                                       delegate:nil                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
              alertView.tag = 1;
              [alertView show];
              [alertView release];

          }
}
```